# How to access a password protected PDF file on Google Drive using Apps Script

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, password-protection

I receive a bill monthly through email which is a password protected PDF file. The file always has the same password. I'm ultimately trying to use Google Apps Scripts (and Drive API) to take the file from Gmail, save it onto my Drive using OCR, to then save that to a separate document which I can take the text from and further use it in my script.

I have simplified my use case here just trying to save the file to the Drive and access it through the script but I can't access it programatically as there doesn't seem to be a way to pass in a password.

```
for (var x in threads) {      
  var messages = threads[x].getMessages();
  for (var y in messages) {
  var from = messages[y].getFrom().slice(messages[y].getFrom().indexOf('<')+1, messages[y].getFrom().indexOf('>'));          
  if (from == 'EMAIL-GOES-HERE') {
    var attachment = messages[y].getAttachments()[0];
    var blob = attachment.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
    var resource = {title: blob.getName(), mimeType: blob.getContentType()};
    var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
    var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
    ...
```

I'm expecting to be able to access the file by passing in the known password; however, since I can't send a password I receive the error: "The document is inaccessible. Please try again later."

Comment: Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no prepared methods of Google Apps Script for opening the PDF protected with the password.

Comment: Ok thanks, that explains why I couldn't find one then  any creative methods you can think of to get it done?

Comment: any thoughts / ideas / updates?

Comment: Although I'm looking for the workarounds, I cannot still find it. The high process cost of Google Apps Script is the bottleneck. I deeply apologize for this. For example, to use the external API is included in the direction you want? By the way, can I ask you about your current situation? If you had found the workaround, can you post it as an answer?

Comment: Ok thank you. I don't have to use the external API, that's just the closest I found as a way to get the PDF text into a text format I can manipulate to pull out the details I need. I have not found a workaround yet - I tried using pdf.js but it threw a multitude of errors I think due to not being strict compliant, and I got lost in that code to be able to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could confirm that you don't want to use the external API. So I cannot resolve your issue, because the process cost of Google Apps Script is very high for decrypting. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Sorry I think we miscommunicated. Using the external API is fine. I'm open to any way to make this work.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `I don't have to use the external API`, I had thought that you don't want to use the external API. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your latest replying, I could confirm that you can use the external API. So I proposed a workaround using the external API. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You want to decrypt the protected PDF file with the password using Google Apps Script.
- You can use the external API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Issue:

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no prepared methods of Google Apps Script for opening the PDF protected with the password. I commented this.

#### Workaround:

Here, as one of several workarounds, I would like to propose to decrypt using an external API. Because to analyze the encrypted file by Google Apps Script leads to much higher process cost. So I would like to propose to use [PDF to DECRYPT API](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-decrypt) of [ConvertAPI](https://www.convertapi.com/). In this case, the process cost of this workaround is much lower than that of the workaround using only Google Apps Script.

#### Preparation:

When you try this, for example, you can also test this using "Free Package". When you try using "Free Package" at [ConvertAPI](https://www.convertapi.com/prices), please Sign Up at "Free Package" and retrieve your Secret key.

#### Sample script:

Before you run the script, please set the variables of `secretkey` and `pass`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var obj = {
    secretkey: "###",  // Your secret key.
    pass: "###", // Password of the protected PDF file.
    blob: blob, // blob of var blob = attachment.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  }
  var blob = decrypting(obj);

  DriveApp.createFile(blob);
}

function decrypting(obj) {
  var url = "https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/pdf/to/decrypt?Secret=" + obj.secretkey;
  var options = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {File: obj.blob, PdfOwnerPassword: obj.pass},
  }
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  res = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  var blob = res.Files.map(function(e) {return Utilities.newBlob(Utilities.base64Decode(e.FileData), MimeType.PDF, e.FileName)});
  return blob[0];
}
```

#### Note:

- When you run `myFunction()` after you set the variables, the unprotected PDF is created to the root folder.
- When you use this script to your script, as one method, please modify as follows.

  ```
  for (var x in threads) {
    var messages = threads[x].getMessages();
    for (var y in messages) {
    var from = messages[y].getFrom().slice(messages[y].getFrom().indexOf('<')+1, messages[y].getFrom().indexOf('>'));          
    if (from == 'EMAIL-GOES-HERE') {
      var attachment = messages[y].getAttachments()[0];
      var blob = attachment.getAs(MimeType.PDF);

      // Added
      var obj = {
        secretkey: "###",  // Your secret key.
        pass: "###", // Password of the protected PDF file.
        blob: blob, // blob of var blob = attachment.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
      }
      blob = decrypting(obj);
      // Added

      var resource = {title: blob.getName(), mimeType: blob.getContentType()};
      var file = Drive.Files.insert(resource, blob);
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(file.id);
      ...
  ```

#### References:

- [ConvertAPI](https://www.convertapi.com/)
- [PDF to DECRYPT API](https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-decrypt)

Comment: This seems like it is in the right direction; however, when using ConvertAPI, it cannot decrypt my PDF file. I get the error "Invalid Password." I've even tried directly on the "https://www.convertapi.com/pdf-to-decrypt" site inputting the proper variables and uploading the file, and I still get the error "Invalid Password." When I use the exact same password on the file locally, it opens up just fine. Something wrong with the API?

Comment: @Scott7004 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I could confirm that the sample script worked. So I proposed it. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So in order to replicate your situation, can you provide a sample PDF file, the password and the sample script for replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm about your issue. Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Scott7004 Unfortunately, I tried the PDF files encrypted with RC4 and AES. I could confirmed that the script worked for them. I cannot still replicate your situation. So it is required your sample for replicating your issue and thinking of the solution. I need your cooperation. Can you do it? I think that this situation is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this situation.

Comment: @Scott7004 Could you please cooperate to resolve your issue?

Comment: Apologies, I got busy yesterday. Thank you very much for your assistance here. I actually sent the file to ConvertAPI themselves to look into. In the meantime, I found ILovePDF which has a better free program (250 files / mo.) I had to directly send to their REST APIs to process the files, including manually creating the payload in multipart\formdata format. After doing so, I was finally able to get the file unlocked so I could progress with the rest of my script to grab the text out of it!

Comment: If you can go ahead and add in reference to other possible External API options like ilovepdf, I'll mark this as answer, as you put me on the right path to figure this out, thanks!

Comment: @Scott7004 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Unfortunately, I cannot find other APIs. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. By the way, can I ask you about the reason of the issue of your PDF file with ConvertAPI? By this, I would like to think of the workaround and solution.

Comment: ConvertAPI hasn't replied to me with an answer on why it wouldn't unlock yet. The API I used and referenced can be found here: https://developer.ilovepdf.com/ for more information.

Comment: Thank you for replying. When you got the response from ConvertAPI, please tell me. I would like to know the reason of the issue. By the way, thank you for the information of `developer.ilovepdf.com`. It seems that you got the solution. So can you post the complete script as an answer and accept it? By this, it will be useful other users.

Comment: Ok, they got back to me today and fixed ConvertAPI to work properly now - so now your solution works, and I will mark it as the answer! I'll also post another answer below with what I ended up doing using ILovePDF. Thank you!

Comment: @Scott7004 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. And I'm glad my script worked for your situation. Thank you, too.